# GCM or Google Cloud Datastore or Google App engine?

Tags: android

I want to create an app that will fetch data from some online server. I am a newbie in this field.
I can't figure what I need. I mean
google cloud messaging or google cloud sql or google app engine?

Can anyone please take a moment to explain me where and for what different purposes they are used and what will fit my need?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention in greater detail your requirements.

GCM is used to send/recieve data from your server.

Google app engine allows you to put your app on the cloud and it is very scalable. --> https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine

If you already have a server and just want to send and receive data, then use GCM